# Fix Content-Type HTTP header issued by jekyll-redirect-from

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-extensions

When building a site using `jekyll-redirect-from`, I am encountering a strange error when redirecting from an old route of a page that includes a file extension (e.g. `the-old-route.md`) in the web browser.

Rather than performing the redirect to the new route, the server responds with the HTTP header `Content-Type: text/markdown` but an HTML document in the body:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Redirecting&hellip;</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost:4000/the-new-route">
  <script>location="http://localhost:4000/the-new-route"</script>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://localhost:4000/the-new-route">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <h1>Redirecting&hellip;</h1>
  <a href="http://localhost:4000/the-new-route">Click here if you are not redirected.</a>
</html>
```

The browser shows this HTML code as text and doesn't run the redirect.

I see the same behavior locally and when the page is hosted in GitHub Pages.

When redirecting from an old route that does not contain a file extension, everything works as expected. Is this a bug with `jekyll-redirect-from` or are routes with file extensions simply not supported?

The page front-matter looks like:

```yaml
---
layout: some-layout
title: A Page
permalink: /the-new-route
redirect_from: the-old-route.md
---
```

Comment: I don't see any info on extensions on https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from - maybe worth asking the author?

Comment: Thanks @Christian - I’ve submitted a bug, but it has been closed due to lack of activity: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from/issues/252.  There’s a similar issue with redirect_to someone else has been trying to get attention to for a long time: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from/issues/232.  The plug-in project seems dead.

Comment: I am sorry for this. We use redirect_from as well, but without any file extension, e.g. as redirect_from: /my-english-filename/. Maybe it makes sense to fork and extent it.